# Return true if array is in ascending order and return false if it isnt

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that accepts an array of numbers as an argument.  If the array of numbers is ascending order it should return true, if not it should return false.

```
arr = [2, 10, 99, 150]

function areOrdered(arr) {
  let sortedArray = arr.sort((a, b) => (a - b));

  if (arr === sortedArray) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just loop through the array, and check if every element is greater than or equal to its preceding element? As soon you find an element which is not, return false, otherwise return true. You don't need to sort the whole array just to check if it's sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could go through the array and check if every value is bigger then the previous.
Something like this:

```js
const one = [2, 10, 99, 150];
const two = [2, 1, 3, 4];

const isAscending = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (i > 0 && arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(one, isAscending(one));
console.log(two, isAscending(two));
```

Comment: You could start `i` at `1` and get rid of the `i > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to detect ascending order:

```js
const data1 = [2, 10, 99, 150];
const data2 = [10, 2, 99, 150];

const isAscending = arr => arr.every((v, i, a) => (i == 0 || v >= a[i - 1]));

console.log(isAscending(data1));
console.log(isAscending(data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stringify the array and then compare. Since `sort` mutates the array, you need to create a new clone using `[...arr]` and then sort

```js
function areOrdered(arr) {
  let sortedArray = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(sortedArray)
}

console.log(areOrdered([2, 10, 99, 150]))
console.log(areOrdered([2, 100, 99]))
```

But the best way to check if the array is sorted is to use a simple `for` and compare with the next index

```js
function areOrdered(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true
}

console.log(areOrdered([2, 10, 99, 150]))
console.log(areOrdered([2, 100, 99]))
```

Comment: Does this code express the intent? No it does not. So it is not good code.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ what?

Comment: You've made edits now. I was referring to your initial answer that showed stringify approach only. (On mobile, so by the time I posted the comment, you've already edited I guess...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work (we can use `.some` to check if any two consecutive elements violates the ascending order rule) -:

```
let checkIfAscendingArr = (arr) => !arr.some((item,i) => {
  if(i > 0){
    return (arr[i-1] > item)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- This function returns true if there are one or less items in the array ( the array doesn't pass the condition in the for loop )
- If there is more than one item in the array it will check the value it is iterating over with the previous one. The function will return false ( thus ending the loop ) if the previous number is higher than the current one.
- If all numbers are looped over the array is in ascending order and the function returns true.

```js
function isAscending( array ) {

  for( let i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ){
   if( array[i-1] > array[i] )
     return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

// example tests
let array1 = [1,2,5,5,8]; // true
let array2 = [1,2,7,5,8]; // false
let array3 = [-10]; // true
const result1 =  isAscending( array1 );
const result2 =  isAscending( array2 );
const result3 =  isAscending( array3 );
console.log( result1 );
console.log( result2 );
console.log( result3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most concise solution would be with [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) where you check on the current element and the next one by index. In this scenario if we run out of the index we just compare to `x+1`.

```js
let isOrdered = arr => arr.every((x,i,a) => x < (a[i+1] || x+1))

console.log(isOrdered([2, 10, 99, 150]))
console.log(isOrdered([21, 10, 99, 150]))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a single liner using Array.reduce. I know - single liners compromise readability. But this one is just for fun.

```js
var isAscending = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((p, c, i, a) => {return p === false ? false : c > p ? i === a.length - 1 ? true :c : false}, 0);

console.log(isAscending)
```